# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'

Tags: android

I update to Android 3.0 Grade 4.0

How fix issue?

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            output.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/apk/" + newName);
            if (output.zipAlign) {
                output.zipAlign.outputFile =
                        file("$project.buildDir/apk/" + newName.replace("-unaligned", ""));
            }
```

Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'....

Answer (score 3):

Assign the value to `outputFileName`, per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output):

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```